# how is hf.Registrar.Roles useful when execute fabric-ca-client command

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

From [fabric-ca document](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#enrolling-the-bootstrap-identity), the command `fabric-ca-client register  --id.name admin2 --id.type user --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer,user",hf.Revoker=true'`,

about `--id.attrs '"hf.Registrar.Roles=peer,user"`
 How to use role admin2? Can admin2 enroll some other users instead of admin ????
Does the command has some difference with `fabric-ca-client register  --id.name adminWithoutRoles --id.type user --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs '`???

what is difference between admin and adminWithoutRoles about use it?

Answer (score 0):

The "hf.Registrar.Roles" attribute controls which the type of identity which an identity can register.

The "hf.Revoker" attribute controls which identities can revoke certificates, together with the "affiliation" of the invoker and invokee identities.

See the "Per-endpoint authorization checks" section of https://docs.google.com/document/d/1x7bbSkLt3VLexNMECJXbOYJ3xX8Ck9Q6O6W1dmnVaRQ for an in-depth description of how they are used.

Comment: As what I said, could admin2 enroll new identity like admin enroll admin2?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use role admin2?

admin2 is not a role, it is a user.

> Can admin2 enroll some other users instead of admin ????

It dependes on the role that it has. In this case no, because is a user of type *user*.

> Does the command has some difference with fabric-ca-client register 
>   --id.name adminWithoutRoles --id.type user --id.affiliation org1.department1 --id.attrs '???

No, there is no difference, they are the same type of user so, they have the same role.

> what is difference between admin and adminWithoutRoles about use it?

This question is the same as "*Can admin2 enroll some other users instead of admin ????*" adminWithoutRoles is a user of type *user* so, it could't enroll other users.